# Sql Possiblelity Route Destination

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Above Picture is the Bus Route Table,
Bus Route Like this:-
**New York > Malaya Road > Kingston Road > New City**

however i would like to get the Result Like below:

[image]

Result is the List of Passenger possibility use the bus to the destination

I m using MySql

Comment: It's really unclear how you're turning the input set of four rows into the output set of six rows. There is no way to answer this, as you haven't really *asked* anything, just given us two seemingly unrelated data sets and said you want to get one from the other.

Comment: I think the first row is wrong on the second image, he want to show `New York Street - Malaya Road` otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: @JorgeCampos sorry, i was Corrected the Picture ! Thanks

Comment: See my answer to your question.

Comment: @ChenYe Dont forget to accept the answer if it fits to you and if you choose it among others :)

Comment: all are wrong, because i want to follow the Location_Seq to generate possibility of routes, but no one provide the correct answer

Comment: is follow Location_Seq not the location_id

Comment: Location_Seq is the sequence of the route, starting from 1 to 4

Answer (score 3):

I think your image is a little bit wrong since the first registry is to show

```
    from_loc              to_loc
New York Street         Malaya Road
```

So, the query you need is this:

```
select a.loc_id from_loc_id, 
       b.loc_id to_loc_id, 
       a.loc_name from_loc,  
       b.loc_name to_loc,  
       a.route_id
  from routes a,
       routes b
 where a.loc_id < b.loc_id
order by a.loc_id, b.loc_id
```

I changed the names a bit.
See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4443a1/5

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
     Select  l1.location_Id as From_Loc_Id,
             l2.location_Id as To_Loc_Id,
             l1.location_name AS From_Loc,
             l2.location_name as To_Loc,
             l1.route_id as Route_id        
     from Location l1,Location l2
     Where l1.location_Id < l2.location_Id
```

[SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea86/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea86/2)

Answer (score 1):

I belive you are making this table based on routes so you have to join using route_id and use condition on loc_id in order to avoid duplicates:

```
select a.loc_id from_loc_id, 
   b.loc_id to_loc_id, 
   a.loc_name from_loc,  
   b.loc_name to_loc,  
   a.route_id
from routes a inner join routes b 
  on a.route_id = b.route_id and a.loc_id < b.loc_id  
order by a.loc_id, b.loc_id
```